# How can I open another app from inside the android default the browser?

Tags: android, browser

When on android default browser long press on the back key opens the history tab. Is there a way to open my own app instead of the history tab by similar user action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is discussed here. 
[Launch custom android application from android browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser)

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your activity as an intent receiver for the long keypress intent in the browser.

Comment: How do I do that? I mean what is the name(or value) of the intent and what is the category?